# Browser back button after log out

Tags: php, caching, logout

How can i prevent browser using the cached copy of the page after log out ?

When user logged out still they can access the previous pages by using the back button.

I understand that we cannot disable the back button (as per SO answers).

Currently i have a large number of pages in different scenarios so i cannot modify each and every page.

**What i have tried**

1. Setting the expire header (do i need to set this on each and every page ? also if i do this does browser cache the page contents ? ( because  i need the browser to cache contents if user is logged in ))
2. I have already a polling system ( but still there is a delay to detect  )
3. Javascript based solution ( it works, but still users can use history option to navigate or a long press in back button )

I am really stuck here , Could you please help me to solve the problem ?

Comment: Why you want to do that, he cannot do anything after session has been ended, any click and he will be thrown out again...

Comment: @Mr.Alien I understand that. But still my client thinks that this is an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this code will help you, use this code in parent controller constructor.

```
//Log out Back
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies.
```

Comment: Could you please explain what will happen after ? i need the browser to cache the contents if he is logged in.

Comment: It will clear the cache, when you logout the site. When you login the site, cache will take the user login values automatically.

Comment: is it for a specific page or entire domain ?

Comment: The user can loged in many browsers for a sigle site. If the user can logout in one browser , it clear the cache in that browser only.

Comment: but how and where should i use this tags , i am woking in a php language

Answer (score 0):

This is the link answers all.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/549347/Browser-Back-Button-Issue-After-Logout

I tried above all solutions but browser incompatible.

So better way is to do Ajax post or in page load check for session var null or not.

This tip also has a **limitation** that when user clicks the back button of the browser, the back page shows for 1 or half second because of executing the WebMethod. but works for sure in all version of any browser!!