# Safari back button issue after logout

Tags: php, session, safari

I am working on a website which is going good with Chrome and Firefox, but when I logout using Safari and then press browser back button it came back to the page before without checking session.

So is there any method that I can use to prevent browser back button or implement session check on back button.

I have checked it out in SO and Googled it but didn't find any solution for me.

Comment: I guess that what you see is the page from the cache when you hit the back button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser back button after log out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780205/browser-back-button-after-log-out)

Comment: @machineaddict : yes, but it is acting like a bug in website. Changes reflecting after logout.

Comment: @bhargavg : I'm checking that out right now.

Comment: @bhargavg: This is not working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Add attribute in the body tag to force Safari to reload the page: (onunload="")

```
<body onunload="">
```

Comment: this no longer works for current version of safari.  still a prroblem

Comment: I have this same problem (sort of). When I view my site on localhost I see this back button problem. When I view my site from my server I do not see this back button problem. The code is identical, the only differences are in security settings. On my server I have ssl installed and can only access the site via https, another difference is HSTS is enabled. Therefore I get a different set of headers for the server than localhost. I haven't been able to pinpoint what actually fixes the problem, but his may help narrow where you look.