# Browser back button is showing previous page after logout in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using grails-2.4.5 version and spring-security-core-2.0-RC5. I have set a default target URI in config.groovy page. When user login then they can access to that page, when logout no access, should display only login page.

My problem is, when user logout login page is displayed, but if browser back button is hit then the default target page is displayed although he can't access any action. But it odd. My config is given below:

in config.groovy >>

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/dashboard/index'    
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
```

my url mapping class >>

```
    class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(controller:"login", action: "auth")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

my default target uri method >>

```
    class DashboardController {

    def index() {
    }
}
```

Comment: The back button will show the previous page because the browser caches it.

Comment: @Amiy how to solve

Comment: You can add headers to not-cache and revalidate see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17780340/10669139). See [this post](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/549347/Browser-Back-Button-Issue-After-Logout-2) for more details.

Comment: @Amiy already tried this answer, no luck

Comment: If you have tried something new, then please add this to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways to stop,

> Browser back button is showing previous page after logout

- With JavaScript, you can clear location history or disable back button.

  ```
  <script>
  history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
  window.onpopstate = function () {
      history.go(1);
  };
  </script>
  ```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/dhavalt10/pen/rGLBzB)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript) you will get many possible options

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: I am using 2.4.5 version. But the documentation is for 4.0.0. Is it possible to use AuthInterceptor in my version? if so then some example will be so nice

Comment: @SumonBappi Please check https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.4.5/guide/theWebLayer.html#interceptors

Comment: As I understand this will only work if any request is passed to the controller, But when I click browser back button no action is being called, just the cached view is shown. I want to display there login page.

Comment: ohh then, best way to go with JavaScript

Comment: Thanks, I will test later and make your answer as accepted.

Comment: This problem should not be solved with the back button manipulation. This is browser cache issue and should be solved with proper headers that are suggested in the above comments in the question itself